# PYQT Selected Combobox item should remove an item in another combobox

Tags: python-3.x, combobox, pyqt5

I am very new in Python and just want to build an ui with PYQT. My problems are mainly the mechanism between two comboboxes. In one combobox, the selected item should remove an item in another combobox.

I tried this:

```
self.ui.combobox1.activated.connect(self.combobox2)  

def remove_Item(self):                            
       if self.ui.combobox1.?????(.currentselection?) == "selected item (name or Index?)": 
             self.ui.combobox2.removeItem(self, Index)
       elif....
```

Combobox 1 give an activation signal to combobox 2, maybe i miss the point that the function is not related to the activated signal? The function asked, if the one item is selected in combobox 1, it should remove the item in combobox 2.

To be more clear --> My aim is that at the end is an application where iam able to select an employee in a combobox "xy" who is ill or in vacation and this employee should disappear in another combobox. Iam struggling with this task and iam very frustrated. Maybe, someone has a solution for my problem. :)

Update:

```
import sys
from qtpy import QtWidgets

from ui.mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowTitle("ZSP")


        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.B29.addItems(['','xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz'])
        self.ui.comboBox.addItems(['','xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz'])

        self.ui.comboBox.activated.connect(self.example_1)

    def example_1(self):
        index = self.ui.comboBox.findText("xxx")
        self.ui.B29.removeItem(index)
        index_1 = self.ui.comboBox.findText("yyy")
        self.ui.B29.removeItem(index_1)
        index_2 = self.ui.comboBox.findText("zzz")
        self.ui.B29.removeItem(index_2)





window = MainWindow()

window.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When i run this code:

It does not matter which item i would select, it always remove "zzz" and "xxx". Even though I try to seperate each item to a function while these functions correspond to self.ui.combobox.currenTextChanged.connection(self.def_1/def_2/def_3) for example. Sorry that i have dramatically missed the point of the example :-/

Comment: Does your code look like this,

`self.ui.combobox.currenTextChanged.connection(self.def_1)
self.ui.combobox.currenTextChanged.connection(self.def_2)
self.ui.combobox.currenTextChanged.connection(self.def_3)`

If yes, that means you link the signal to three slots, so when you emit the **currenTextChanged** signal, Qt will help you to trigger all the linked slots, says def_1, def_2, def_3. That's why you always delete items you don't want to delete.

Comment: So, you don't have to define three different slots, you can just define one slot, and this slot should have one argument, becasue the currenTextChanged signal will emit current selected text to you. Just as the example I've answered.

Comment: So i have tried to define one function which is connected. When i start the program and select one of these in the comboBox, all items disappeared in B29. Only the selected should disappear. How can i solve this problem? Thats my last question, i promise ;)                           
        self.ui.comboBox.currentTextChanged.connect(self.example_1)

        def example_1(self, text):
        self.ui.B29.removeItem(self.ui.B29.findText('xxx'))
        self.ui.B29.removeItem(self.ui.B29.findText('yyy'))
        self.ui.B29.removeItem(self.ui.B29.findText('zzz'))

Comment: Try this :)

`self.ui.comboBox.currentTextChanged.connect(self.example_1) 

def example_1(self, text): 
self.ui.B29.removeItem(self.ui.B29.findText(text))`

Comment: God bless you! :) I thought text concerning a name.  You helped me so much. I would spend you a beer if i could :D

Comment: Come on~ I like beer.

Answer (score 2):

PyQt has signal/slot mechanism, that is you can do some slot when some signal is being triggered.

For example, in your case, QComboBox has **currentTextChanged** signal, it will be triggered when you select an item in combobox. When this signal is triggered, you can link it to your slot, and the slot will do the things you want, delete item in another combobox.

Here's an example code :

```
class MainWindow(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.combo1 = QComboBox()
        self.combo2 = QComboBox()
        self.combo1.addItems(['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'])
        self.combo2.addItems(['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'])
        # This line link the signal - currentTextChanged to slot - del_item_in_combo
        self.combo1.currentTextChanged.connect(self.del_item_in_combo)
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.combo1)
        layout.addWidget(self.combo2)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.setWindowTitle("combo box demo")

    def del_item_in_combo(self, text):
        # currentTextChanged signal will pass selected text to slot
        index = self.combo2.findText(text)  # find the index of text
        self.combo2.removeItem(index)  # remove item from index
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! You helped me a lot! :) But I have one more problem regarding the function and slot. Where i do the mistake here? If i want to remove the selected item in combobox, it also delete the other items connected to the function. The combobox remove an item, but the main challenge for me is when i call the function with more than one removeItem function. When i start the program and two remove.item are in it, it would remove both instead of the one selected. E.g. I select "xxx" in a cb of "xxx" and "yyy" while both items are in the function it remove both.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand your question. The combobox remove item by index, do you pass all the index to your slot when trigger the signal? Or you call the clear() method of combobox, so it will delete all items in it.

Comment: I will post my code, hopefully i would be more clear. Sorry! The object of my aim is a collection of names in a combobox and when i select the name in the combobox, the exact name should be remove in another combobox. It worked pretty good for the first name, also i have tried a "for" loop. But i think my experience in python go not to far. Something like: If this person is selected in the combobox 1, this person should disappear in combo 2 if its true, else if it checks the other names when selected.